# How to pass custom option with triggering an backbone event or adding/removing/changing collection

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js

From the Backbone link :

http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog

**if you'd like to prevent the event from being triggered, you may pass {silent: true} as an option. Note that this is rarely, perhaps even never, a good idea. Passing through a specific flag in the options for your event callback to look at, and choose to ignore, will usually work out better.**

I am looking for an example how we can pass a custom option (specific flag in above lines) when we add to, remove, or update the collections and specially when we are triggering our own event.

passing my flag into options, then retreving on callback side get nothing.

This is what i did :

```
var coll = new Backbone.Collection.extend({
   //
});
```

register event :

```
coll.add(aModel, {myFlag : true});
```

listening event :

```
coll.on('add', function(model,collection,options){
  console.log(options.myFlag);
  //prints undefined
});
```

Also for my custom event :

register event :

```
coll.trigger('myEvent', {myFlag : true});
```

listening event :

```
coll.on('myEvent', function(model,collection,options){
  console.log(options.myFlag);
  //prints undefined
});
```

Comment: @Koka, you said "passing my flag into options, then retreving on callback side get nothing". Could you post the code that you used? I just ask because you want to know how to pass a flag in the options and then you say that you passed a flag in the options and it didn't work, so it would be nice to see what you already tried so that we can explain what you should do differently.

Comment: please look at the edited portion

Comment: @Koka, the `add` listener and handler looks perfect. I just tested something similar and it works. Are you sure there isn't a typo somewhere in your original code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your arguments wrong... 
For Custom events:

```
coll.trigger('myEvent', {myFlag : true});


coll.on('myEvent', function(options){
  console.log(options.myFlag);
});
```

As for your `"add"` event example, it works:

```
var coll = new Backbone.Collection();
coll.on('add', function(model,collection,options){
  console.log(options.myFlag);///Prints True
});
coll.add({}, {myFlag:true});
```

Notice that the initialization of coll is different from your version